# Python 3.6: Iterating through the length of a file and only keeping html table tags

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I should preface that I am very new to Python and am completely lost as to how I would go about coding the solution to my problem.

I have a text file that contains the following html code for example:

```
<table class="infobox" style="width: 315px; border-spacing: 2px;">
<td>Builders:</td>
<td>
<ul style="list-style: none; margin: 0px;">
<li style="text-indent: -0.4em; padding-left: 0.4em;"><a href="/wiki/Ingalls_Shipbuilding" title="Ingalls Shipbuilding">Ingalls Shipbuilding</a></li>
<li style="text-indent: -0.4em; padding-left: 0.4em;"><a href="/wiki/Bath_Iron_Works" title="Bath Iron Works">Bath Iron Works</a></li></ul</td></tr>
<tr style="vertical-align: top;">
<td>Operators:</td>
<td><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" class="thumbborder" data-file-height="650" data-file-width="1235" height="12" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg/22px-Flag_of_the_United_States.svg.png" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg/33px-Flag_of_the_United_States.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg/44px-Flag_of_the_United_States.svg.png 2x" width="22"/> </span><a href="/wiki/United_States_Navy" title="United States Navy">United States 
  Navy</a></td></tr>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is iterating through each line and looking for tags that do not equal or contain `<table, <td, <tr, </td>, </tr>, </table>` 
and then finding the ">" and removing everything between or replacing with an empty string.

The goal is to just keep the table tags with the raw text.  From what I've read there's the soup.meta() or other functions that isolate tags but I'm not sure about it's implementation.  I understand the logic should be something like this:

```
for the length of the file
    if the first so many characters do not equal the tags listed above
          then find the > and replace everything in between < and > with ""
    else leave it alone
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're probably better looking into [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). I appreciate it's not so simple if you're new to Python but it will probably make your life easier in the long run. HTML is pretty complex to parse.

Comment: Don't try to treat HTML as raw text.  You'll almost certainly do more work than you really need to, and end up with a bad result after a lot of frustration.  You're much better off finding a parser that actually knows how to read HTML.

Comment: Thank you!  After researching BeautifulSoup it looks like the "decompose" function will be a good starting point.